# is it safe to delete a "login.keychain.sb..." file?

Tags: macos, mac, osx-mavericks

I donwloaded MPlayerX and it seems it had a bunch of Addware.  Anytime I type something in Safari it will take so some advertisement site, like MacKeeper, ZipCloud etc...

Now I was looking in my keychain folder and I found 4 keychain files that were updated around the time I downloaded MPlayerX.

Somewhere I was reading and they say to delete all files, applications etc... that were downloaded to remove the Addware.

Is it safe for me to delete those 4 files, how can I see what is in these keychain files ?

Thanks,
Patrick

Comment: Did you ever find out?

Answer (score 0):

You can look with Keychain Access, which should be there with your OS (probably in Utilities folder) to see what keychain files are in use and their contents.

Alternatively look into the CLI "security" executable using terminal, refer to the man page for help on security commands.
The impact of deletions should most likely only be on that MPlayerX app, but best to see as above what is in the keychains first. That also gives you a chance to see what MPlayerX was storing.

Did you try the MPlayerX support/website forum etc?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).